# Which technique can be to validate more than 1 field in form on their equality?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have 2 fields: for password and for its confirmation, and wanna check their equality via some common validator.
How can i make it more effective way?

```
private val model = object : ViewModel() {
    val password = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
    val confirmPsw = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
}

override val root = form {

    fieldset("Admin") {
        field("Set password and confirmation") {
            val tf1 = textfield(model.password) {
                promptText = "Place password"
                requestFocus()
            }.required()

            val pf1 = passwordfield(model.confirmPsw){
                promptText = "confirm password"
            }.required()

            button("set") {
                enableWhen { model.valid }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did with it (after tons of cigs and coffees):

First we make model for entering and checking password.

```
private val model = object : ViewModel() {
    val password = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
    val confirm = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
    // This makes boolean binding for control equality.
    val equal = booleanBinding(confirm, password) {
        confirm.value == password.value && confirm.value.isNotEmpty()
    }
}
```

And then we can use it for button enabling.

```
button("OK") {
    enableWhen { model.equal }
}
```

Not sure it is best way, but it works. Is there a better way?
(BTW, we can put it in 'snippets' too)